# How to deply OpenL Tablets with Docker?

Tags: docker, rule-engine

I want to deploy [OpenL Tablets](http://openl-tablets.org/) with Docker. I used the official Docker image for [OpenL Tablets WS](https://hub.docker.com/r/openltablets/ws/).

**Deploy OpenL Tablets**

I started the Docker container as documented:

> **To use file system repo**
>
> To run OpenL Tablets Rule Services with filesystem datasource you can mount your local folder to the container:
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d --rm -p 9080:8080 -v <path_to_datasource>:/root/.openl/openl-ruleservice/datasource openltablets/ws
> ```
>
> - ```
>   -e ruleservice.datasource.filesystem.supportDeployments=true - enables support for deployments
>   ```

**Deploy rule**

For testing I copied the unzipped first [tutorial](http://openl-tablets.org/documentation/tutorials) into the mounted directory, see [Chapter 4: Deploy OpenL Tablets Web Services](http://openl-tablets.org/files/openl-tablets/5.12.0/OpenL%20Tablets%20-%20Installation%20Guide/SMPUserDeployOpenLTabletsWebServices.html)

> c. Put your rule project to the appropriate datasource folder. Every rule project should be represented as a separate folder. As an example you can use OpenL Tablets Tutorial that you can download from the OpenL Tablets web site.

**Result**

After entering URL `http://localhost:9080` I see:

[image: Screenshot]

What did I do wrong? Why is the tutorial not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in the non-Docker installation guide, see [OpenL Tablets BRMS
Installation Guide](http://openl-tablets.org/files/openl-tablets/5.23.0/OpenL%20Tablets%20-%20Installation%20Guide.pdf):

> ### 4.2 Configuring OpenL Tablets Rule Services for a Local File System Data Source
>
> Using a file system as a data source for user projects means that projects are stored in a local folder. This folder
> represents single deployment containing all projects. Each project must also be represented as a separate folder.
> This is the default data source configured in the system.
>
> To deploy OpenL Tablets Rule Services, configure a local file system as a data source as follows:
>
> 1. Navigate to the `<TOMCAT_HOME>\webapps` folder and extract the OpenL Tablets Rule Services WAR file.
>    For example, right click the OpenL Tablets Rule Services WAR file name and select **7-zip > Open archive**.
>    For more information on downloading OpenL Tablets Rule Services as a WAR file, see Downloading
>    Preconfigured OpenL Tablets Rule Services.
> 2. Navigate to the `WEB-INF\classes` folder, open the `application.properties` file, and for the
>    `ruleservice.datasource.dir` setting, define the address to the folder with projects.
>
>    For example:
>    `ruleservice.datasource.dir = d:/datasource/`
>
>    Note that for proper parsing of Java properties file, the path to the folder must be defined with a slash (‘/’)
>    as the folders delimiter. Back slash “\” is not allowed.
> 3. Check if the property is defined as `production-repository.factory = org.openl.rules.repository.LocalRepositoryFactory`.

After adding environment variables

- `production-repository.factory`
- `ruleservice.datasource.dir`

it works.

```
docker run  \
  --detach  \
  --publish 9080:8080 \
  --mount type=bind,source=/home/ubuntu/openl/datasource,target=/root/datasource,readonly \
  --env production-repository.factory=org.openl.rules.repository.LocalRepositoryFactory \
  --env ruleservice.datasource.dir=/root/datasource \
  openltablets/ws
```

Comment: You can also try to use `ruleservice.deployer.enabled = true` property. It adds the button to deploy projects